# Ubuntu - Windows incompatibility on C++/Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

The C++ projects I wrote and run without any problems on Ubuntu return the exception "vector subscript out of range" when I run them on windows. I use Windows 7 and Visual C++ 2008 Express.

I hope that makes sense to someone.

Comment: Can you reproduce a minimal example code and post it? I know sometimes this is hard, however without any code at all, it's hard to guess what is wrong, unless someone already encountered the same situation.

Comment: I do not know which part of the code causes the error, and it's not only one project. I get the same error for 3 different projects.

Comment: Visual Studio has a great debugger.  Just set a break point and run the program in debug mode.  Or just run without break points and take a look at the call stack to see where you are when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the STL shipped by Microsoft comes with [checked iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965%28VS.90%29.aspx), which when run in debug mode ensure that your vector indices are in range. No such checking is done in GCC by default.

Answer (score 1):

Your code almost certainly contains undefined behavior. In such a case, an implementation is free to do almost anything it wants. It appears that gcc has basically ignored the problem, so it wasn't apparent. VC++ has built enough self-monitoring into your code to find the problem and tell you about it.

The next step is pretty much up to you: find the problem in your code and fix it. Unfortunately since you haven't posted any of the code, it's essentially impossible to give much more detailed advice about what you should do or how to do it. About the only hint I can think of is that the debugger in VC++ does have a nice stack trace feature, so if you run the code under the debugger and it fails, it's pretty easy to walk back up the stack to find the code that called the function (that called the function, etc.) where the problem was detected.